# C++: Extend member type in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'd welcome some help with C++ inheritance to get a better grasp of the concept.
Is it possible to "extend" member types when creating a derived class? I think my problem can be best demonstrated by a simple example, where I'd like to extend the class *VehicleData* with a new double variable:

```
class VehicleData {
 int yearOfManufacture;
 //Different routines, for example Serialize(), etc., warranting to create a class for just a bunch of variables
};

class BicycleData:VehicleData {
 double frameHeight; //new property that only applies to bicycles
};

//Now I create the actual classes that use the types above
class Vehicle {
 VehicleData data;
 void PrintData(); //a function that works on basic vehicle data
};

class Bicycle:Vehicle {
 BicycleData data; //should copy VehicleData when creating an instance of this class
};
```

The problem with this approach is that when I code the above and create a Bicycle instance, its BicycleData member *hides* the already existing VehicleData member.

Is there a way to *extend* the base class, i.e. simply add a new double variable (to store frame height in this example), and keep the already existing (year of manufacture) data?

Comment: Why do you need separate `XXX` and `XXXData` classes?

Comment: @Barmar Let's say I'd like to include XXXData (which is just a list of variables) in a different project, which for example saves XXXData to disk but doesn't use all the methods and dependencies of XXX.

Comment: Why can't you simply use another name for the derived class?

Comment: `BicycleData moredata;`

Comment: Why inheritance for `class BicycleData:VehicleData` ?

Comment: Make a virtual function getData(). in the Bicycle it will access the BicycleData, PrintData should not access data member directly but through the virtual access method. So it will get access to the data of the derived calss and print the known part of this derived class data

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky if you go down that road, one must be sure to completely remove 'data', else there will be 2 years of manufacture to keep up to date.

Comment: @HJuls2 That would be a workaround, of course! But then for every method and reference I'd have to keep track which data member is stored where. For example the PrintBicycleData() would have to first print VehicleData members then bicycle-specific data second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no clean way to do *exactly* what you want with inheritance alone.

You could create a template out of your base class:

```
template <typename Data>
class BaseVehicle
{
    Data data;
// etc.
};

class Vehicle : BaseVehicle<VehicleData>
{
// etc.
};

class Bicycle : BaseVehicle<BicycleData>
{
// etc.
};
```

Then the `Vehicle` and `Bicycle` classes would contain `data` field of `VehicleData` and `BicycleData` types respectively.

Since in your example `Bicycle` inherits from `Vehicle` *privately* (i.e. there is no support for using `Bicycle` polymorphically via pointer/reference to `Vehicle`), this would effectively be identical to what you want to achieve.

---

If you *do* want dynamic polymorphism, you should create a separate, preferably abstract, class, defining the interface for your vehicles, e.g.:

```
class VehicleInterface
{
public:
    // Some pure virtual interface methods
    virtual void moveTo(const Vector2 position) = 0;

    virtual ~VehicleInterface() = default;
};
```

And then you can have your concrete vehicles inherit and implement this interface:

```
class Vehicle : BaseVehicle<VehicleData>, public VehicleInterface
{
public:
    virtual void moveTo(const Vector2 position) override
    {
        // implementation for Vehicle
    }
};

class Bicycle : BaseVehicle<BicycleData>, public VehicleInterface
{
public:
    virtual void moveTo(const Vector2 position) override
    {
        // implementation for Bicycle
    }
};
```

Then any function, which would like to work with vehicles polymorphically, can just accept a reference or a pointer to `VehicleInterface`:

```
void driveToWork(VehicleInterface* vehicle)
{
    vehicle->moveTo(getWorkPosition());
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: True, thanks. I intended public inheritance with polymorphism, but indeed the example I wrote lacked it.

Comment: @Szak1 See my edit for a possible option on how to approach polymorphism in this case.

Comment: I assume that basevehicle would extend the vehicleinterface.  You could then have the Bike class not extend the interface.

Comment: @TerraPass Thank you for the update. I've had to read a bit to understand your syntax and indeed this is an elegant workaround. Marking this answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer; Not in the way that you're aiming for, but you can achieve something similar.

Rather than have an instance declared as you have, if you make data a pointer. You can then have BicycleData inherit VehicleData and then just replace data with the new instance in the constructor of the Bicycle.

ie

```
class Vehicle {
  void PrintData();
  protected:
    void replaceData(std::shared_ptr<VehicleData> d) {
      data = d;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<VehicleData> getData() {
      return data;
    }

    template<class T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> getDataAs() {
      return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(data);
    }
  private:
    std::shared_ptr<VehicleData> data;
};

class Bicycle:Vehicle {
  Bicycle(){replaceData(std::make_shared<BicycleData>());}

  std::shared_ptr<BicycleData> getData() {
    return getDataAs<BicycleData>();
  }  
};
```